# t() strings can't able to translate

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm wondering that Drupal **t()** strings are not available for the translation.

Let me explain what I did. I'm going to make my site as multilingual (English & Dutch). English is my source language.

For this, I have added locale module and enabled English and Dutch language.

Then I installed [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) && [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module on my site.

And then I wanted to show some multilingual text in the user profile edit form. Hence I put form alter and given some string inside t('My topics').

Then I went to **/admin/config/regional/translate/translate** this page to add a translation for my custom string "My topics". But it not available there.

Where did I'm going wrong?

I'm using 
 - Drupal 7.54
 - Enabled Drupal's core **locale** module
 - Entity Translation(7.x-1.0-beta6)
 - Internalization (7.x-1.17)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

Initially, my site is in English(source language).

We have to switch the language to other languages on the site(in my case it is Dutch) using this path **admin/config/regional/language**. Then, we have to view the page which is consists of t(). Then only the t() strings would register for translation.

Now go to **admin/config/regional/translate/translate** and search your t() string, it will be available and add translation !!!